# How do I make a border for a resume span multiple pages in Latex?

Tags: formatting

I'm using the package `fancybox` to create a border around my resume however, I'm not sure how to alter the length and width parameters such that it extends to the portion of my resume on the second page.

More specifically, I don't want the border to continue onto the second page with the top cut off (as if it were all one continuous page) but rather to be one whole border all of its own. That is, encompass the stuff on the second page just as on the first.

This is an empty slate of my resume with all the info removed:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}  
\textwidth=5.2in 
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document} 

\thisfancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(7,9.8)}


\name{} 
\address{} 

\begin{resume} 

\section{Objective} 


\section{Education} 



\section{Leadership}

 {\bf ,}  \hfill   {\bf 2012-2013}
        \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt  % reduce space between items
        \item              
        \item                   
 \end{itemize}



{\bf ,}  \hfill   {\bf 2013-2014}
        \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt %reduce space between items
        \item                   
        \item                  
        \item                  
        \end{itemize}

{\bf ,}  \hfill   {\bf 2011-2012} 
                 \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
                 \item                  
                 \item                 
                 \item 

         \end{itemize}


\section{Experience} 

{\bf ,}   \hfill   {\bf 2012} 
                \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
                \item 

                \item  

            \end{itemize}

{\bf ,}  \hfill {\bf 2013}                
                \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
                 \item  

                 \item 

                  \item
         \end{itemize}


\section{Work}

                 {\bf  ,}       \hfill                                {\bf 2010-2014} 
                 \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt

                 \item                    
                 \item                    
        \end{itemize}

\section{Hobbies}


\section{Academic Honors} 

% Tabulate Computer Skills; p{3in} defines paragraph 3 inches wide
\section{Computer \\ Skills}
   \begin{tabular}{l p{3in}}
    \underline{Languages:} &  \\

     \underline{Software:} &  
 \end{tabular}

\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a **complete** Minimal Working Example demonstrating your issue. That is much more useful than mere fragments of code.

Comment: Oh wow, how do I include my tex code in the question so it appears properly formatted?

Comment: That is my resume with all the info removed since it is irrelevant but essentially, with the amount of info I have, it splits into two pages at Academic Honors, and then the border is gone.

Comment: Do you want borders on all pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\fancyput*` since `\thisfancyput` affects only the current page.  The starred version adds to, rather than replaces, other things that have been inserted with `\fancyput` or `\thisfancyput`.

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\textwidth=5.2in
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\fancyput*(3.25in,-4.5in){
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(7,9.8)}



\name{}
\address{}

\begin{resume}

\section{Objective}


\section{Education}



\section{Leadership}

 {\bf ,}  \hfill   {\bf 2012-2013}
        \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt  % reduce space between items
        \item
        \item
 \end{itemize}



{\bf ,}  \hfill   {\bf 2013-2014}
        \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt %reduce space between items
        \item
        \item
        \item
        \end{itemize}

{\bf ,}  \hfill   {\bf 2011-2012}
                 \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
                 \item
                 \item
                 \item

         \end{itemize}

\newpage
\section{Experience}

{\bf ,}   \hfill   {\bf 2012}
                \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
                \item

                \item

            \end{itemize}

{\bf ,}  \hfill {\bf 2013}
                \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt
                 \item

                 \item

                  \item
         \end{itemize}


\section{Work}

                 {\bf  ,}       \hfill                                {\bf 2010-2014}
                 \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt

                 \item
                 \item
        \end{itemize}

\section{Hobbies}


\section{Academic Honors}

% Tabulate Computer Skills; p{3in} defines paragraph 3 inches wide
\section{Computer \\ Skills}
   \begin{tabular}{l p{3in}}
    \underline{Languages:} &  \\

     \underline{Software:} &
 \end{tabular}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, don't use two letter commands like `\bf` but use `\bfseries`. Further, the same job can be done in a colourful way with `tikz` in conjuction with `eso-pic/background` packages. Please do ask if you are interested.